# How to fix “SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable”?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

My OS is centos7 with one physical NIC. I want to test openstack so I create a tap/tun device:

```
tunctl -t tap0
```

and config the IP to 192.168.88.10.

In order to share network with my physical NIC, I use the following cmd:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i tap0 -s 192.168.88.10/24 -m conntrack -- 
ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

But the virtual NIC tap0 still can't access internet. `ping -I tap0 8.8.8.8` failed.

my route table:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         132.122.xxx.254 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
132.122.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
```

How to make tap0 access the network?

Comment: tap interfaces work at level 2 (ethernet). TC/IP routing have no effect on tap interfaces. Usually you need to bridge your interface with a real, physical interface to use it. Furthermore, usually for virtualisation you don't need to create and setup your tap device manually.

Comment: Openstack requires 2 NICs but I have only one so I have to create a virtual interface. Can I change it to a tun device (level 3) to make it work?

Comment: Openstack requires 2 NICs for production setups, not for testing. Start here: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/DevStack

Comment: A tun or tap interface has to be tied to a process: that's the other end of the virtual wire. Like QEMU, Virtualbox, VMware or various VPN softwares ... even ssh or sshd. Your ping would be routed to this process.